# ios - How to calculate how much memory a UIView animation will take?

Tags: ios, memory, uiview

I am new to IOS development.
In my application I've got several images that I am animating.
The number of images can vary.

When running on ipad 2 the animations works fine.
When running on ipad 1, which a large number of images (20+) the app just crashes with a memory warning.

I would like to calculate the amount of memory an animation would take in advance.
Based on this figure I could calculate if to go through with my animation or skip
to the final status.

How can this be done?

Edited:

My current code:

```
- (void)remix
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:
     @selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    self.currentStatus = canvas_status_animating;
    NSMutableArray *circles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (CircleView* view in self.subviews)
    { 
        if(![view isKindOfClass:[CircleView class]])
            continue;
        [circles addObject:view];
    }

    [self animatePosition:circles];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


-(void) animatePosition:(NSArray*)circles
{
    int maxWidth = self.bounds.size.width; 
    int maxHeight = self.bounds.size.height;


    for (CircleView* view in circles)
    {  
        int selectedX = 0;
        int selectedY = 0;
        if ((arc4random()%200)+1 > 100)
        {
            selectedX = (arc4random() % maxWidth) + 1; 
            selectedY = (arc4random() % 200) + 1;
            selectedY = (selectedY > 100) ? (maxHeight - selectedY) : selectedY;
        }
        else 
        {
            selectedX = (arc4random() % 200) + 1; 
            selectedX = (selectedX > 100) ? (maxWidth - selectedX) : selectedX;
            selectedY = (arc4random() % maxHeight) + 1;
        }                                

        view.frame = CGRectMake(selectedX - view.frame.size.width / 2, 
                                selectedY - view.frame.size.height / 2,
                                view.frame.size.width, 
                                view.frame.size.height);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call this function before and after, and calc the difference.

```
-(double)availableMemory
{
    vm_statistics_data_t vmStats;
    mach_msg_type_number_t infoCount = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;
    kern_return_t kernReturn = host_statistics(mach_host_self(), HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vmStats, &infoCount);

    if (kernReturn != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
        return NSNotFound;
    }

    return ((vm_page_size * vmStats.free_count) / 1024.0) / 1024.0;

}
```

Comment: before and after running the animation? it kind'a misses the point, as if I run the animation and there's not enough free memory the app will crash

Comment: You're going to check it at run time?  Memory checks should be done as an optimization technique not as a preventative measure while the app is running.  If your animations are taking up too much memory you should optimize the images, consider streaming them from disk, or use cocos2d, sprites, or something else.  I will tell you that animation with UIKit that has delays is often the animation queue and not memory.

Comment: what do you mean by often is the animation queue and not memory ?

Comment: Well depending on how you are queueing up your animations they sometimes get put in the back of the line.  iOS is constantly animating things.  You might post your UIView animations so we can see them.  Also you can try grouped CALayer animations or AffineTransform animations as well.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Are you wanting them to animate all at once or sequentially?

Comment: I would use CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to move all of your circles and then CGAffineTransformConcat to concat all of your affine transforms into a group and then commit them.

Comment: hi, well I tried wrapping my head around CGAffineTransformConcat. I am not sure though, how could I animate multiple views using only a single CGAffineTransformConcat?

Comment: @MattHudson  quote: "Memory checks should be done as an optimization technique not as a preventative measure while the app is running."  I think there's some low level implementation differences (e.g. virtual table for class hierarchy) and nothing wrong with memory measurement at runtime.

Comment: Fair enough.  Obviously you want to do as much optimization is as possible during development, and don't use a runtime measurement as a check against leaks that could be fixed during development.